# Change tab color according to two different cells (if statement)

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, tabs

I've trying to change the tab color following a if logic, for cells C32 and C46. Even though the logic is working for most o the logic some does not bring me the right color. I'm not super familiar with VBA.

What is not working:

```
C32= Fail and C46= Not Complette (brings me green instead of red)
C32= Not applicable and C46= Not Applicable (brings me red instead of gray)
C32= Not applicable and C46= Not Complete (brings me green instead of gray)
C32= Not Complete and C46= Not Complete (brings me green instead of gray)
C32= Not Complete and C46= Not Applicable (brings me red instead of gray)
```

Please help. It seems simple to fix but could find the solution

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Range("$C$32").Value = "Pass" And Range("$C$46").Value = "Pass" Or Range("$C$46").Value = "Not Complete" Then
         Me.Tab.ColorIndex = 10
    ElseIf Range("$C$32").Value = "Pass" And Range("$C$46").Value = "Not Applicable" Then
        Me.Tab.ColorIndex = 48
    ElseIf Range("$C$32").Value = "Pass" And Range("$C$46").Value = "Fail" Then
        Me.Tab.Color = vbRed
    ElseIf Range("$C$32").Value = "Fail" And Range("$C$46").Value = "Fail" Or Range("$C$46").Value = "Not Complete" Or Range("$C$46").Value = "Not Applicable" Then
        Me.Tab.Color = vbRed
    ElseIf Range("$C$32").Value = "Fail" And Range("$C$46").Value = "Pass" Then
        Me.Tab.ColorIndex = 10
    ElseIf Range("$C$32").Value = "Not Applicable" And Range("$C$46").Value = "Not Applicable" Or Range("$C$46").Value = "Not Complete" Then
        Me.Tab.ColorIndex = 48
    ElseIf Range("$C$32").Value = "Not Applicable" And Range("$C$46").Value = "Fail" Then
        Me.Tab.Color = vbRed
    ElseIf Range("$C$32").Value = "Not Applicable" And Range("$C$46").Value = "Pass" Then
        Me.Tab.ColorIndex = 10
    ElseIf Range("$C$32").Value = "Not Complete" And Range("$C$46").Value = "Not Applicable" Or Range("$C$46").Value = "Not Complete" Then
         Me.Tab.ColorIndex = 48
    ElseIf Range("$C$32").Value = "Not Complete" And Range("$C$46").Value = "Pass" Then
       Me.Tab.ColorIndex = 10
    ElseIf Range("$C$32").Value = "Not Complete" And Range("$C$46").Value = "Fail" Then
        Me.Tab.Color = vbRed
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: It would be helpful to know what *should* be happening in addition to what is not happening correctly

Comment: Why the switch between `Me.Tab.ColorIndex` and `Me.Tab.Color`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Some remarks:

1. You are using the `SelectionChange` event (is that the intention?) if it is, change my code to use it
2. I organized the code in Select Case Statement which (IMO) is easier to read
3. I added parenthesis to understand better the options related with C46

**Code:**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_change(ByVal Target As Range)
    ' Suggest that you define a range to watch when changed for this (un comment and adjust next line if you consider it)
    ' If not intersect(Target, me.Range("c32:c46")) Then Exit sub

    changeColorTab Me, LCase$(Me.Range("c32").Value), LCase$(Me.Range("c46").Value)

End Sub

Private Sub changeColorTab(ByVal targetSheet As Worksheet, ByVal c32Value As String, ByVal c46Value As String)

    Dim targetcolor As Long

    Select Case True
    Case c32Value = "pass" And (c46Value = "pass" Or c46Value = "not complete")
        targetcolor = 10 ' Green
    Case c32Value = "pass" And c46Value = "not applicable"
        targetcolor = 48 ' Dark grey
    Case c32Value = "pass" And (c46Value = "fail")
        targetcolor = 3 ' Red
    Case c32Value = "fail" And (c46Value = "fail" Or c46Value = "not complete" Or c46Value = "not applicable")
        targetcolor = 3 ' Red
    Case c32Value = "fail" And c46Value = "pass"
        targetcolor = 10 ' Green
    Case c32Value = "not applicable" And (c46Value = "not applicable" Or c46Value = "not complete")
        targetcolor = 48 ' Dark grey
    Case c32Value = "not applicable" And c46Value = "fail"
        targetcolor = 3 ' Red
    Case c32Value = "not applicable" And c46Value = "pass"
        targetcolor = 10 ' Green
    Case c32Value = "not complete" And (c46Value = "not applicable" Or c46Value = "not complete")
        targetcolor = 48
    Case c32Value = "not complete" And c46Value = "pass"
        targetcolor = 10
    Case c32Value = "not complete" And c46Value = "fail"
        targetcolor = 3 ' Red
    Case Else
        targetcolor = -4142 ' Light grey
    End Select

    targetSheet.Tab.ColorIndex = targetcolor


End Sub
```

Let me know if it works

Comment: Hi @ricardo. Thank you so much! I dont usually use excel macros so I dont know much. It worked. I really appreciate your time answering my question.